# Can't build PYQT on Linux

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, pyqt4, redhat

I am building `pyqt4` with `python2.7` on redhat 6.  I've installed `python2.7` from the sources, which works fine for everything else I've tried.  When I run  `python2.7 configure.py`, I get the following error:

```
\# python2.7 configure.py
```

Determining the layout of your Qt installation...
Error: Failed to determine the layout of your Qt installation. Try again using the `--verbose` flag
to see more detail about the problem.

I've read that the way around this, is to issue the following command, which appeared to work:

```
\# python2.7 configure.py --qmake /usr/bin/qmake-qt4 -g
```

This completed successfully.  But when I run make, I get the following error.

```
make[1]: Entering directory /root/Downloads/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.11/qpy<br />
make[2]: Entering directory /root/Downloads/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.11/qpy/QtCore<br />
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o w_qpycore      -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread<br />
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:<br />
In function _start: (.text+0x20): undefined reference to main<br />
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status<br />
make[2]: [w_qpycore] Error 1<br />
make[2]: Leaving directory /root/Downloads/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.11/qpy/QtCore<br />
make[1]: \*\*\* [all] Error 2<br />
make[1]: Leaving directory /root/Downloads/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.11/qpy<br />
make: \*\*\* [all] Error 2<br />
```

Thanks for any help. - Mark

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem as you. Was told we're supposed to use 'configure-ng.py' instead, but I get this error when I run that:

```
    Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
    Determining the details of your Qt installation...
    An internal error occured.  Please report all the output from the program,
    including the following traceback, to support@riverbankcomputing.com.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "configure-ng.py", line 2816, in <module>
        main(sys.argv)
      File "configure-ng.py", line 2780, in main
        target_config.from_introspection(opts.verbose, opts.debug)
      File "configure-ng.py", line 695, in from_introspection
        self.qt_shared = (lines[1] == 'shared')
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

EDIT -- Figured it out.

Turns out I had Qt 4.6 installed locally, and the installer is expecting Qt 4.7+ (although the error messages didn't say that). I installed Qt 4.8 using these repositories (worked on CentOS 6): https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/fedora-kde/2013-March/012437.html

After adding those repos, I just did **yum install qt qt-devel** and it upgraded my Qt from 4.6 -> 4.8

After getting Qt 4.8 locally, cd to the PyQt4 source files and:

```
    1. python configure-ng.py
    2. make
    3. make install
```

EDIT2: Turns out we need Qt 4.7 at work. After some research, turns out these versions are happy together:

```
   PyQt 4.10.4
   SIP 4.15.4
   QT 4.7.4
```

Qt 4.7 RPMs can be found here: http://joseph.freivald.com/linux/2011/09/23/qt-4-7-4-and-qt-creator-2-3-0-for-centosrhel-5/

PyQt 4.11 DOES NOT work with Qt 4.7 (at least for me, i'm on CentOS 6.4)
With those versions, just follow the 1,2,3 steps above.